# 12 future numbers required in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have one requirement in SQL where
We have couple of market ids
Let say 20,30,40

And here for each market using one plsql function we are getting one campaign number let's say for market 20 I got 20210306,for mrkt 30 we got 20210307, and for 40 mrkt id 20210308.

Now what I want to achieve for each market we should have current campaign no as 20210306 as well as 12 future campaign should be produced by SQL query based on each  current campaign of the market.

I am doing it using union all and campaign+1,2,3 and so on which is taking time . Do we have some brief logic for it.

Please suggest
Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`, and `CREATE FUNCTION`) statements for your table(s) and function(s); the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data; **YOUR** current SQL query; the issues/errors with **YOUR** code; and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate series of data (numbers or dates or even characters) using the `LEVEL` pseudo column with a `CONNECT BY` clause.
In your case, it sounds like you want generate the next 10 numbers starting from 20210306.
That could be done like this:

```
WITH current_campaign ( nr ) AS 
( SELECT 20210306 FROM dual )
SELECT
  nr + level
  FROM
  current_campaign
CONNECT BY
  level < 13;

  20210307
  20210308
  20210309
  20210310
  20210311
  20210312
  20210313
  20210314
  20210315
  20210316
  20210317
  20210318
```

The 20210306 could also represent the date March, 6, 2021. If you want to generate those numbers date based numbers you could do that too. For example (starting from 0629 so the result shows the month change, only showing 5 rows)

```
WITH current_campaign ( cdate ) AS 
( SELECT DATE'2021-06-29' FROM dual ) SELECT
  TO_CHAR(cdate + level,'YYYYDDMM')
  FROM
  current_campaign
CONNECT BY
  level < 6;    

20213006
20210107
20210207
20210307
20210407
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a brief logic , I will try to implement this by tomorrow and I hope this will satisfy my needs ,logic seems accurate and will upvote on this by tomorrow. Once again many thanks for your time

Comment: Glad to be of help